# Array Declaration and Access in External Dictionaries in Clickhouse

Tags: arrays, mongodb, clickhouse

I am connecting to mongodb using external dictionaries in clickhouse.It works fine with integers and strings but when it comes to Array(UInt8) it gives error saying table doesn't exist

**Error :**

Code: 50, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown type Array(UInt8), e.what() = DB::Exception

Is there any way to declare Array(UInt8) as attribute in external dictonary and access array of mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

Current it's not supported to use composite type for dictionaries. Here are all the supported types.

```
AttributeUnderlyingType getAttributeUnderlyingType(const std::string & type)
{
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, AttributeUnderlyingType> dictionary{
        { "UInt8", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt8 },
        { "UInt16", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt16 },
        { "UInt32", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt32 },
        { "UInt64", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt64 },
        { "UUID", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt128 },
        { "Int8", AttributeUnderlyingType::Int8 },
        { "Int16", AttributeUnderlyingType::Int16 },
        { "Int32", AttributeUnderlyingType::Int32 },
        { "Int64", AttributeUnderlyingType::Int64 },
        { "Float32", AttributeUnderlyingType::Float32 },
        { "Float64", AttributeUnderlyingType::Float64 },
        { "String", AttributeUnderlyingType::String },
        { "Date", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt16 },
        { "DateTime", AttributeUnderlyingType::UInt32 },
    };

    const auto it = dictionary.find(type);
    if (it != std::end(dictionary))
        return it->second;

    throw Exception{"Unknown type " + type, ErrorCodes::UNKNOWN_TYPE};
}
```